# spring boot, how to get server port in filter's init method

Tags: spring-boot

My English is so poor. I hope you can know what I mean.

I need get server port in init method of my filter. The next is my filter configuration:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filter.setFilter(new Monitor());
    filter.addUrlPatterns("*.json");
    return filter;
}
```

The next is my method to get server port for tomcat:

```
public static Integer getPort() throws Exception {
    MBeanServer server = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0);
    Set<ObjectName> names = server.queryNames(new ObjectName("*:type=Connector,*"), null);
    for (ObjectName name : names) {
        String protocol = server.getAttribute(name, "protocol").toString();
        String scheme = server.getAttribute(name, "scheme").toString();
        logger.debug("protocol={}, scheme={}", protocol, scheme);
        if (protocol.toLowerCase().contains("http") && scheme.toLowerCase().contains("http")) {
            return (Integer) server.getAttribute(name, "port");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's run well in sample tomcat application. But in spring boot application, it's just get 0.

This question bothers me for a long time. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the port in your filter via `ServletRequest.getServerPort()`

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    int port = request.getServerPort();
    System.out.println("serverPort:" +serverPort);
}
```

OR, Put `server.port=8080` to your `application.properties` or `application.yml` and pass it to your filter:

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private int port;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filter.setFilter(new Monitor(port));
    filter.addUrlPatterns("*.json");
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: That's not my need. I want to get port in init method(javax.servlet.Filter#init)

Comment: @HowardLiu I have changed the solution for your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need other solutioin. The `server.port` must be given in application.yaml or use -D in cammand. Or there is an exception, 
 `Could not resolve placeholder 'server.port' in value "${server.port}"`, occured. My filter is a base component for others. That's not elegant if I ask others to give this parameter.